# Is there a shorter / more concise way to validate fields in SvelteKit?

Tags: typescript, forms, performance, validation, sveltekit

Currently, I am using a bunch of utility functions, as well as the SvelteKit `$` operator to determine whether a form is valid or not as follows:

```js
<script lang="ts">
    const required = (str: string) => str.length < 1;
    const length = (str: string, minLength: number, maxLength: number) => str.length < minLength || str.length >= maxLength;

    $: errors = {
        name: 
            required(fields.name) ? "Name is a required field." : 
            length(fields.name, 3, 5) ? "Must be between 3-5 chars." : ""
    }

    $: valid = !errors.name;

    const onSubmit = () => {
        if (valid) {
           // ...
        }
    }
</script>
```

My question is: Is this an efficient way of validating fields? If I have many fields, will a change re-calculate the *whole* `errors` object, or only the required field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using native validation?

```html
<form onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); alert('submitted');">
  <input name="Name" required minlength=3 maxlength=5 />
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

If you have anything more custom, there are also functions for that.

- [`setCustomValidity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setCustomValidity) - Specify any error message, clear via setting `''`, should be done on any input/change.
- [`reportValidity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reportValidity) - Manually report validation errors (exists for inputs and forms).
- [`checkValidity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/checkValidity) - Get whether a form/input is valid without reporting the errors.

There are also properties on the inputs which give you a message ([`validationMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#validationmessage)) or a detailed state with various flags that describe what is wrong ([`validity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#validity)).

To output a native validation message instead of the popups, you can use the `invalid` event. If your structure is rigid you can e.g. add an action to the input that automatically outputs the error in its next sibling:

```html
<script>
    function onSubmitClick(event) {
        const form = event.target.closest('form');
        const valid = form.checkValidity();

        if (valid == false) {
            event.preventDefault(); // Prevents error popups
            [...form].find(e => e.validity.valid == false)?.focus();
        }
    }
    
    function validationErrors(node) {
        const output = node.nextElementSibling;
        node.addEventListener('invalid', onInvalid);
        node.addEventListener('input', onInput);
        
        function onInvalid() {
            output.textContent = node.validationMessage;
        }
        
        function onInput() {
            if (node.validationMessage == '')
                output.textContent = '';
        }
        
        return {
            destroy() {
                node.removeEventListener('invalid', onInvalid);
                node.removeEventListener('input', onInput);
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<form on:submit|preventDefault={() => alert('submitted')}>
    <input name="name" required minlength=3 maxlength=5 use:validationErrors />
    <div class="error"></div>

    <div><button on:click={onSubmitClick}>Submit</button></div>
</form>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/813494d0fab64a46b69173faea2bcd02?version=3.55.1)

This only shows the errors when the user tries to submit the form which is what I would recommend. It is not polite to berate the user when they have not even finished writing.

If the DOM structure is not as rigid, one could use `bind:this` to get element references or use something like `data-` attributes to associate the elements with each other.

It may also be useful to extracts things to separate components. The action itself can be extracted to any JS file.

Comment: `checkValidity` does seem quite useful as I could use it `on:input` to update the error message, but is there a way to take the native validation message (or `setCustomValidity` message) and use it as the value for another tag (i.e. the `<div class='input__error-message'>` that I use after my input)

Comment: I added an example for something like that.